# Why is the input current for a forward converter negative for a short time?

Tags: current, converter

We have made some lab excercises with a forward converter and I was wondering why the input current of a forward converter is negative for a short time. Screenshot of oscilloscope can be seen below, the yellow is input current and blue output current. Thanks!
[image: Oscilloscope of input current (yellow), output current (blue) and duty cycle (green)]

Comment: Show your schematic.

Comment: Impossible to say. Maybe your scope is set to AC coupling. And we don't know how your circuit works.

Comment: @Justme Well, in the lower right hand side I see "Coupling: DC". Might be a clue there.

Comment: @jonk But it is not for the yellow channel but for the blue channel 3, says on top of the green coupling button.

Comment: @Justme Ah. My mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the schematic of your forward converter. From [here](http://www.idc-online.com/technical_references/pdfs/electrical_engineering/Forward_Type_Switched_Mode_Power_Supply.pdf) is a typical one.

[image]

Observe the direction of current in the reset winding.